# SQL Developer Schema Name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Database with a SID and a connection where I have edited tables and such. I am trying to connect to the database but where would I find out what my Schema is called? As far as I understand my SID is the database name and I have a username and a connection name. Is one of these the schema name?

Thanks!
Margaret

Comment: To all intents and purposes yes, user name = schema name.

Comment: [A database user owns a database schema, which has the same name as the user name.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-0311EEA5-72A5-421E-A646-636EFDC5ED72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below to get schema name.

`select sys_context('userenv','session_user') from dual`